# How do I make a table with out of 3 lists in python?

Tags: python, list

I have 3 lists I need to make a table of, the lists are something like:

```
movies = ['pirates1', 'indiana1', 'nemo1', 'spiderman1']
viewers = ['AnnA', 'Dirk123', 'Jessica_Ewa', 'AliB']
ratings = [[0, 2, 3, 1], [1, 4, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 4], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

The actual lists are much longer and the usernames(viewers) are long aswell, so it is pretty hard to align everything right.

```
                 pirates1  indiana1  nemo1  spiderman1
AnnA             0         2         3      1
Dirk123          1         4         0      0
Jessica_Ewa      1         1         0      4
AliB             0         0         0      0
```

Hard coding is not allowed for the assignment.
Help would be very much appreciated!

EDIT:
I tried this already:

```
moviesString = '\t\t'
for e in range(len(movies)):
    moviesString = moviesString + '    ' + movies[e]
print(moviesString)
for x in range(len(viewers)):
    finalLine = viewers[x] 
    for y in range(len(ratings[x])):
        finalLine = finalLine + "\t" + str(ratings[x][y])
    print(finalLine)
```

Comment: "for the assignment" Is this homework?

Comment: yes it is homework

Comment: Then... shouldn't *you* do it?

Comment: Yes I should, but I have tried for 5 hours straight already and everytime in doesn't work well

Comment: Then show what you tried.

Comment: I edited it with what I tried

Comment: See the last example in the example section: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples

Comment: What don't you like about your solution?  Must-haves of all bug reports: ① What was done, including the complete setup of the situation, ② What was expected, ③ What was observed instead (and in this case I might add: where's the relevant difference).

Comment: For proper alignment check the [Format String Syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) Section which explains a width option.